# Convert contour to broken line in image Matlab

Tags: matlab, contour, dotted-line

I have the following problem in Matlab: I have a 2D closed contour (a set of 2D coordinates of points) representing an object like in this image:
[image: image representing 2D contour]

I want to convert it into a broken line contour like: dot-line-space-dot-line-space, etc.

Is there a way to solve this problem in Matlab?
Thank you very very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first fill in the object using `imfill`, then trace it using `bwboundaries`, and plot the result using `plot` with [a given line style](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html#f26-701421).

```
% Load the image in and convert to binary
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4NLh.png');
img = img(:,:,1) > 170;

% Fill in the middle hole and compute the boundary
boundary = bwboundaries(imfill(img, 'holes'));

% Plot the boundary on a black background
plot(boundary{1}(:,2), boundary{1}(:,1), ...
            'LineStyle', '-.', ...
            'Marker', 'none')

axis image
axis ij
```

[image]

**Update**

Oh...you already have the x/y points. Oh well! Just use the `LineStyle` property of plot to accomplish what you want.